# What does Oracle's lawsuit against Google mean to Android developers?

Tags: java, android

What does [Oracle's lawsuit against Google](http://mashable.com/2010/08/14/google-rebuts-oracle-lawsuit-invokes-open-source-defense/) mean to Android developers? I know this is not a programming related question, but I can't think of another forum where I can ask this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is the future of Java doomed in light ofthe current Google Oracle lawsuit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486981/is-the-future-of-java-doomed-in-light-ofthe-current-google-oracle-lawsuit)

Comment: This is the place to ask this... in the FAQ it is written that you can ask questions with "matters that are unique to the programming profession".

Comment: @Alerty: Lawsuits aren't unique to the programming profession.  Also, the FAQ says to "Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion."

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: The question itself is not on the lawsuit. It is about the effects of the lawsuit on the Android developers. I agree that this question is argumentative.

Comment: This is also a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486981/is-the-future-of-java-doomed-in-light-ofthe-current-google-oracle-lawsuit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically speaking Oracle is going out on a limb with this one.  Android isn't actually Java, it's a Java -> Dalvik converter.  No one has won a lawsuit against converters, although no one to my knowledge has tried.  You'd be best to follow things on TechCrunch or some other nearly technologically related press-like site.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean much.  If Oracle wins, Google will pay damages and/or license the patents in question. Android isn't going to stop shipping.