# Java: Consequences of the Oracle/Google lawsuit

Tags: java, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does Oracle's lawsuit against Google mean to Android developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597128/what-does-oracles-lawsuit-against-google-mean-to-android-developers)
>   [Is the future of Java doomed in light ofthe current Google Oracle lawsuit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486981/is-the-future-of-java-doomed-in-light-ofthe-current-google-oracle-lawsuit)

What are the possible consequences the Oracle/Google lawsuit will have for the future of the Java programming language?

Comment: @Michael Petrotta: That question was specifically about Android development.

Comment: Maybe closed for the wrong duplicate (that one was about Android), but here is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486981/is-the-future-of-java-doomed-in-light-ofthe-current-google-oracle-lawsuit

Comment: If you agreed that the linked question was argumentative, why did you bother to post this one?  This isn't the place for questions that require speculation.

Comment: @Thilo: I am not asking if the language is doomed... I am asking about the possible consequences that it be positive or negative.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Would you prefer that I removed the word 'possible' so it does not require speculation?

Comment: @Alerty: this question is around ongoing litigation.  Regardless of language, it will require either speculation or a time machine.

Comment: There's been quite a bit of discussion on this topic at Hacker News that might interest you, though.  See [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1604612), [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1607210), and [here](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1599584).  Also, [search results](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=oracle+google+site%3Anews.ycombinator.com&btnG=Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

Comment: @Alerty: No, I don't think that will help.  None of us knows yet what the consequences will be, so *possible* consequences are all we could really speculate about.